# Is there a more efficient way of selecting the data than multiple intersects SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, intersect, relational-division

I have data in my PostgreSQL database in the format below

```
answer_id    question_id    country_id    answer
    1             1              1           7
    2             1              2           7
    3             1              3           5
    4             2              1           3
    5             2              2           2    
    6             2              3           2
```

What I am trying to do is get all countries which have a certain answer for a certain country, and we can have multiple question~answer combination. 
For example I can need all countries which for question 1 have 7 for an answer (2 values), but then, along with the first condition) I also add that answer for question 2 is 2 and now it drops from 2 values (countries under ids 1 and 2) to only 1 (country id 2).

Now **I have managed to do it with intersect** as it follows...

```
select country_id from answer_table where question_id = 1 and answer = 7
intersect 
select country_id from answer_table where question_id = 2 and answer = 2
```

**Problem** is that I need to be able to do this dynamically, meaning that one time I may select only 1 question~answer pair, but other times I may want more (3, 5, 7 or whatever) which affects the number of selects (and in turn intersects).

I mean this above works and I do have a capability to use a query builder so it really isn't a big deal to generate, but I don't believe that it is the most efficient nor the smartest way.

Therefore, my question is basically is there a more efficient or smarter way of doing these selects/intersects dynamically (like function which takes arrays of data or whatever?)?

Thank You and have a good one!

p.s. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811171/multiple-sql-select-where-with-intersect-placeholder-value) stack thread, but there they use fixed 5 queries at all times.

Comment: I like the intersection approach. It is very readable and with such a clear query the DBMS should not have problems to find a good execution plan. An index on `(question_id, answer, country id)` will probably speed this up immensely. The other typical approach to this is aggregation as shown in Gordon's answer.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and by doing a bit of digging it says to avoid using it on columns with a great amount of null values. This answer is only 1 type of answer and there are 3 other types of answers in the answer table and only 1 of those 4 columns can be filled in a single row. Most commonly it is the type my question is related to, but not as often to benefit from indexing. 
That is my understanding :)

Comment: In PostgreSQL you can use partial indexes that only contain relevant data. Something along the lines of `create index idx on answers (question_id, answer1, country id) where answer1 is not null;`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/indexes-partial.html

Comment: oh well that makes it a bit different, thank you for the answer @ThorstenKettner!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner just wanted to tell you thanks again, indexing was faster, but partial indexing is lightning quick :D
Nice one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is more efficient, but you might find it more generalizable:

```
select country_id from answer_table
where (question_id, answer) in ( (1, 7), (2, 2) )
group by country_id
having count(distinct (question_id, answer) ) = 2;
```

You can actually replace the `in` list and "2" with array functions to pass in array values.

Comment: Dope, this seems to work well, I will analyze the queries and get back to you in this thread about the efficiency of both. What I would like is if you could just explain how to use array here? I understand that 2 represents the array length (as it needs to have answers for all given combinations), but how do I swap the given with the array data?

Comment: Got it with array functions, thanks a bunch!
It looks like this:
```select country_id from answer_table
where array[question_id, answer] <@ ARRAY[[1,7], [2,2]]
group by country_id
having count(distinct (question_id, answer) ) = array_length(ARRAY[[1,7], [2,2]], 1);```

Comment: @Mr.Fabulous . . . Good.  I wasn't able to get back to this in a timely manner.