# Select rows with same id but with multiple *specific* values in another column

Tags: sql

I have a question similar to [Select rows with same id but different value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162812/select-rows-with-same-id-but-different-value-in-another-column) but with an added requirement: I need rows matching *specific* values.

I have a table like this:

| ID | TAG |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | C |

And I want only the rows that have *at least* `TAG` values with `A` *and* `B` specifically (having more tags is not a problem). I.e. there are many different tag values and I only want rows where the same `ID` is associated with both `A` and `B`.

So the output for this hypothetical query would be:

| ID |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

These queries are being built on the fly by a program, so it is fine if they contain hardcoded values for, e.g. `A` and `B`. So a valid answer could be just a query for my specific example table. I just want to get a feel for the general pattern these queries need to have.

Ideally, this would also easily be extensible to an arbitrary number of hard-coded `TAG` values.

Comment: An ID must have at least A and B associated? I.e. An ID with three rows A, B and C would be considered a match? Or must it be exactly the two values, so an ID with three values would be dismissed?

Comment: An ID with three rows A, B, and C would also be a match, yes. It just needs to have *at least* A and B. I've updated the description and example table to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the logical intersection between two sets, SQL provides the [`intersect`](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-intersect/) operator for exactly this:

```
select id
from t
where tag = 'A'
intersect
select id
from t
where tag = 'B';
```

Comment: This ended up being the most easily extensible option using syntax as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811171/multiple-sql-select-where-with-intersect-placeholder-value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m1.ID
FROM mytable1 m1
INNER JOIN mytable1 m2 ON m2.ID=m1.ID AND m2.TAG='B'
WHERE m1.TAG='A'
```

see: [DBFIFFLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/w6KKFwop)

Select every record with tag 'A', and do an inner join to the same table finding the values 'B' (with the same ID).

Answer (score 0):

Or also filtering for the two tags, group by `id` and apply a `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = <number of tags>` filter on the grouped data:

```
WITH
-- your input ...
indata(id,tag) AS (
          SELECT 1,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'B'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'C'
)
-- end of input, real query starts here
-- replace following comma with "WITH"
SELECT
  id
FROM indata
WHERE tag IN('A','B')
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using `HAVING` combined with `CASE` clause :

```
SELECT id
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TAG = 'A' THEN 1 END) = 1
       AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TAG = 'B' THEN 1 END) = 1
       -- AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN TAG NOT IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 END) = 0 -- This can be added to select IDs that have exactly A and B tags.
```

Comment: this is a variant of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77426551/724039  (I do draw no conclusion on either on of the being more, or less, correct than the other one....)

Comment: Agree, However, my solution does not need counting the number of tags and can be easily extended to match exactly tags A and B.